# How to display comment in page source

Tags: html

I want to display comments in my HTML source, but only in the source and not on the actual rendered content of the page. For example, when a user right clicks their browser window and selects "View Source", I want the comments to be visible for them to read there, but I don't want the comments to be visible on the actual rendered website.

I tried

```
<span style="visibility: hidden;">
    Joe Hancock - 04/16/12 - Some comment
</span>
```

But doing this takes up actual room on the webpage (white space) and really throws off my styling.

Anyone know of an good way to do this?

Comment: Protip: You can use `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<!--This is a comment. Comments are not displayed in the browser-->
```

HTML Comments

Comment: @JonathanPayne, definately wrong for Chrome. I can't comment of other browsers

Comment: *Every browser* (and I mean **every**) shows comments in the "view source".  That's kinda the entire point of comments.

Comment: Mmm.. I was using JSF with it.. and it wasn't showing the comments in the source :/ You're correct though, I just tried a plain html document. My apologies.

Comment: @JonathanPayne: What's "JSF"?

Comment: Ah... duh. I'd tried the asp comment tags, but didn't think to try the html ones. Duh duh duh. Thanks for helping me through this brief bout of stupidity. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<!-- Comment goes inside here -->
```

Comment: Please let's stop sending people to W3Schools. Event beginners.

Answer (score 0):

```
1<div style="display:none">This is hidden</div>2
```

Comment: That's a hidden `<div>`, `<!-- not a comment -->`.

Comment: `<!-- comments -->` *ARE* visible in the source code, that's the whole point of them.  http://jsbin.com/ihapec/2/

Comment: @Rocket, though it isn't the best solution, it isnt incorrect, it does what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: That's like saying you can use a screwdriver to hammer a nail.  It's not the best solution, but it'd work.  I like to use the correct tool for the job.  In this case, if you want a comment, use a comment.

Comment: Hidden divs are _not_ comments.